# Images in CSS not displaying when run through MAMP localhost

Tags: css, codeigniter, web, mamp

Just started building a website and its my first time using MAMP and CodeIgniter Framework. I am trying to get images from the CSS code to display but they are not showing up when I open the website in the localhost. My question is:

Do I need to put the images in a specific location in MAMP's docs? or is there something I am not configuring first?...(I bet its something tiny I have not done..) Just to note I have tried changing the URL and file location a few times but had no luck..

Here is the CSS code which links to the image I am trying to display, everything else works except the images are not displaying.

Please help.

```
#header {
overflow: hidden;
width: 1000px;
height: 50px;
margin: 00px auto 20px auto;
background: url(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/application/views/images/img03.jpg) no-repeat right top;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/application/views/images/img03.jpg` to `/application/views/images/img03.jpg`

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried this and changing URL's a few times but still no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
background: url(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/application/views/images/img03.jpg)
```

"localhost" points to htdocs, you must set starting the route from there

```
background: url(/website/application/views/images/img03.jpg)
```

can use with F12 if you use chrome if the correct path to the image

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this as well but no luck..I forgot to mention I was using CodeIgniter in the question so I don't know if that helps answer a few questions?..

Comment: CSS, JAVASCRIPT, IMAGES, ETC  is allowed to be accessed directly, maybe you should create a directory "static"  for these files in root of your directory

Comment: Fixed it! Needed to create a folder in the main website folder rather than under application. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change your images path. For example, if you have your css file in a folder called `css`, your images are in `views` and the 2 folders are on the same level:

```
background: url(../views/images/img03.jpg) no-repeat right top;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried this and changing URL's a few times but still no luck

Comment: you have to show your folder structure.. your paths are the issue without doubts

Comment: Probably would of helped if I actually informed everyone what Framework I am using :s ...I am using CodeIgniter so its under their file structure if that helps?

Comment: nope, it still doesn't tell where is your CSS. Can you provide the path, like you did for the image - `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/application/views/images/img03.jpg`?

Comment: The CSS is in a folder css inside the views folder and that displays fine

Comment: Would it make a difference to place the CSS in with the HTML and save that as the .PHP file?

Comment: Fixed it! Needed to create a folder in the main website folder (website/assets) and put the images in there, rather than under application/views/images. Thanks for your help!